# How do you get a name (apart from birth) in the scriptures?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, puranas, ramayana

As I know, there are characters that have the name "Dhananjaya" (Arjuna) to conquer many kingdoms, but I have not seen that Karna, Nakula, Sahadeva, Bhima or Bharata have that name.

Also that one of the names of Bhurishrava is "Bhuridakshina" for his donations, but Karna made donations as well but does not have a name like that.

So my question is, how do you get a name in the scriptures other than the birth name?